# LINQ recursive query to return hierarchical set of groups

Tags: c#, linq, recursion

Given a list of the following models

```
public class Team
{
    public int TeamId { get; set; }
    public int ParentTeamId { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to write a recursive linq query which will enable me to retrieve a heirarchy that looks like this

```
Team
    ChildTeams
Team
    Team
        ChildTeams
```

I've tried many approaches and seen many similar questions but none of them specifically helped me solve the problem. The latest attempt I tried went along these lines:

```
private class TeamGrouping
{
    public int? ParentTeamId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Team> ChildTeams { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<TeamGrouping> Grouping { get; set; }
}

private IEnumerable<TeamGrouping> ToGrouping(IEnumerable<Team> teams)
{
    return teams.GroupBy(t => t.ParentTeamId, (parentTeam, childTeams) => new TeamGrouping {ParentTeamId = parentTeam, ChildTeams = childTeams});
}

private IEnumerable<TeamGrouping> ToGrouping(IEnumerable<TeamGrouping> teams)
{
    return teams.GroupBy(t => t.ParentTeamId, (parentTeam, childTeams) => new TeamGrouping{ParentTeamId = parentTeam, Grouping = childTeams});
}
```

I would pass the list of teams into the first `ToGrouping(IEnumerable<Team>)` and then subsequent returned groups into `ToGrouping(IEnumerable<TeamGrouping>)` but this is producing incorrect results.

Anyone have any advice or ideas?

Comment: So you're starting with a flat collection of Teams, and you want to create a tree? I think you'll need more than just LINQ here (though I'd be very interested to be proven wrong). As you iterate over your collection of teams, you will need to build out a tree, not a collection of IGrouping<T>s.

Comment: Sorry, yeah should have mentioned that it's a flat list of Teams.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So first, your `TeamGrouping` is actually a bit more complex than it needs to be.  All it needs is the `Team` object and a sequence of itself for children:

```
public class TeamNode
{
    public Team Value { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<TeamNode> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Next we'll take our sequence of teams and create a node for each one.  Then we'll use `ToLookup` to group them by their parent ID. (Your use of `GroupBy` is pretty darn close to this, but `ToLookup` will be easier.)  Finally we can just set each node's children to be the lookup value for that node (note that `ILookup` will return an empty sequence if the key doesn't exist, so our leaves will be handled perfectly).  To finish it off we can return all of the top level nodes by just looking up all nodes with a parent ID of `null`.

```
public static IEnumerable<TeamNode> CreateTree(IEnumerable<Team> allTeams)
{
    var allNodes = allTeams.Select(team => new TeamNode() { Value = team })
        .ToList();
    var lookup = allNodes.ToLookup(team => team.Value.ParentTeamId);
    foreach (var node in allNodes)
        node.Children = lookup[node.Value.TeamId];
    return lookup[null];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you will need an object like this, so the Team object might be:

```cs
public class Team
{
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Team> ChildTeams { get; set; }
}
```

Then a recursive function:

```cs
private IEnumerable<Team> BuildTeams(IEnumerable<Team> allTeams, int? parentId)
{
    var teamTree = new List<Team>();
    var childTeams = allTeams.Where(o => o.ParentId == parentId).ToList();

    foreach (var team in childTeams)
    {
        var t = new Team();
        var children = BuildTeams(allTeams, team.TeamID);
        t.ChildTeams = children;
        teamTree.Add(t);
    }

    return teamTree ;
}
```

The first call passes a `null` for parent, and will pull all the teams that have a null parent :), though I notice your teams don't have a null for parent, so not sure how you identify the top level ones currently?

Comment: This works well, one thing I dont get is why you create new Team object, you will get null properties everywhere, why you dont just pass `team` object?

Comment: @fernandospr can you perhaps consider not making these non-edits? It's bumping old questions for no reason

Comment: @CaiusJard SO prompts these to review.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution for when you are using Entity Framework objects you can handle root objects (Parent == null) by removing the Team objects that have a null parent on the first call.

```
public class Team
{
    int TeamID { get; set; }
    Team Parent; { get; set; }
}

public class TeamNode
{
    public Team Node { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<TeamNode> Children { get; set; }
}

private List<Team> BuildTeams(List<Team> allTeams, int? parentId)
{
    List<TeamNodes> teamTree = new List<Team>();
    List<Team> childTeams;

    if (parentId == null)
    {
        childTeams = allTeams.Where(o => o.Parent == null).ToList();
        allTeams.RemoveAll(t => t.Parent == null);
    }
    else
    {
        childTeams = allTeams.Where(o => o.Parent.ID == parentId).ToList();
    }

    foreach (Team team in childTeams)
    {
        TeamNode teamNode = new Team();
        teamnode.Node = team;
        List<TeamNode> children = BuildTeams(allTeams, team.TeamID);
        teamNode.ChildTeams = children;
        teamTree.Add(t);
    }

    return teamTree ;
}
```