# Linq Query For Self Referencing Object to Get Childless Elements

Tags: c#, linq, recursion, lambda

I have a category class as shown.

```
/// <summary>
/// A category / matrix item
/// </summary>
public class Category : BaseItem
{
    public Category()
    {

    }

    [Key]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(256, ErrorMessage = "Text cannot be longer than 256 characters")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Item text is required")]
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public int? ParentCategoryId { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Parent { get; set; }

}
```

I am attempting to write a function that allows me to get only the elements who have no children.  I am struggling to wrap my head around the recursion logic.  I am not opposed to using a loop and just building a list, however I am hoping to be able to do something like joining the data back to itself, `DefaultIfEmpty()`
then join again where joined record is null.

```
IE: 
ID| Text   | ParentId
1 | Parent | null
2 | Child  | 1
3 | asdf   | 2
4 | asdf   | 1
```

I would only want to retrieve records 3 and 4 as they have no children.

I have referenced [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20004587/linq-recursive-query-to-return-hierarchical-set-of-groups) for the full tree functions, but need a bit more to get only the childless elements.

Comment: You can select the `ID` that are not in the `Distinct` of the `ParentId` or you can `GroupBy` that same logic so you have them in 2 list. One that have child and one that doesn't.

Comment: Would you be able to show me an example?  I think i understand what you are saying, but i can't quite get there.

Comment: Something like this WowContext.Categories.Where(x => WowContext.Categories.All(y => x.CategoryId != y.ParentCategoryId)); I'm not quite sure the performance impact of this.

Comment: You could do something like this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/dyIqOS

Comment: @steve16351 thank you so much! that worked like a charm.  I have updated the question with your answer because they still have this marked as a dupe.  thank you for the help!

Comment: @Eric You're using basically the exact same solution as the duplicate.  That the solution works for you is evidence that the question is in fact a duplicate.

Comment: @Servy in that case you can take questions with the linq tag and basically mark 90% of them as duplicates. after all, most questions are simply derivatives of other questions

Comment: @Servy I would respectfully disagree.  I do not see group join anywhere in the answer of yours on the referenced post.  I was thinking the main difference was that I was trying to specifically accomplish the recursive function while also only getting the items that have no children.  The referenced post was just trying to perform the recursive function and create a tree.

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''' Yes, pretty close to it yeah.  Probably not literally 90%, but a very high number.  Why do you think LINQ questions shouldn't be marked as duplicates, like other questions?

Comment: @Eric `ToLookup` and `GroupJoin` are performing functionally the same behavior here.  The group join is a bit more code, but not meaningfully different in behavior here.

Comment: @Servy what is the downside of having duplicates?

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''' It wastes people's time re-posting the same answers, it spreads the answers out over lots of different places, making finding the various solutions harder, and harder to evaluate against each other, it makes it harder to update them when new solutions become available, or problems with existing solutions come up, etc.  What are the advantages of duplicates?

Comment: @Servy people choose how to spend their time, they're not forced to answer...having answers in different places doesnt stop google from indexing them...finding solutions becomes easier not harder...as for the benefits, well, the main benefit of stackoverflow is helping people, if a person cant find the answer to their problem, they post a question and get it answered by someone who wants to answer it

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''' Why do you think finding the solutions for a problem is easier when there are 100 low quality answers posted to duplicate questions instead of 100 duplicates of a *good* question with *good* answers that are all in one place?  Finding any one low quality solution may be easier, finding the good solutions becomes much harder.  Why do you *want* people to waste their time re-posting the same solutions, even if they're not forced to?  If someone can't find the answer to a common problem it gets closed as a duplicate of the question that provides a quality answer.

Comment: @Servy the voting system helps to identify the best solution. _Why do you want people to waste their time re-posting the same solutions_ that's an unfair assumption about me

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''' Yes, the voting system *does* help to identify the best solution.  Which it can do when they're all posted in the same place. When there are 1000 different copies of the question, each with different subsets of the answers, of varying quality, and of various scores, *that voting system can't work*. When they're all posted in one place, *it can do its job* of ranking answers based on their score.  How is that an unfair assumption? You responded to the assertion that lots of people are having their time wasted re-answering duplicates by saying that's a good thing.

Comment: @steve16351 any chance you can vote to repopen?  there is a 3 vote experiment going on through SO META this month and i would like to be able to use your code as the actual answer for others to reference.

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''' would welcome your support to reopen as well to ensure others can reference.

Comment: @Eric i've voted to repoen. others can reference even with this being closed

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''' thank you and i did not know that so thanks for sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments on this question, i was able to accomplish this using the query below.

```
public IEnumerable<Category> GetChildlessCategories()
{
    return WowContext.Categories
    .GroupJoin(
        WowContext.Categories.Where(category => category.ParentCategoryId.HasValue),
        (category) => category.CategoryId,
        (child) => child.ParentCategoryId.Value,
        (category, children) => new { Children = children, Category = category })
    .Where(a => !a.Children.Any())
    .Select(a => a.Category).ToList();
}
```